# Regex to capture VBA comments

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to capture VBA comments. I have the following so far

```
'[^";]+\Z
```

Which captures anything that starts with a single quote but not contain any double quotes until end of string. i.e. it will not match single quotes within a double quote string.

```
dim s as string        ' a string variable   -- works
s = "the cat's hat"    ' quote within string -- works
```

But fails if the comment contains a double quote string

i.e.

```
dim s as string ' string should be set to "ten"
```

How can I fix my regex to handle that too?

Comment: [Repeat Question?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311888/regular-expression-to-get-comments-in-vb-net-source-code

Try `^\'[^\r\n]+$|''[^\r\n]+$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern in [@Jeff Wurz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044801/regex-to-capture-vba-comments?lq=1#comment33424910_22044801) (`^\'[^\r\n]+$|''[^\r\n]+$`) doesn't even match *any* of your test samples, and the linked question is useless, the regex in there will only match *that specific comment in the OP's question*, not "the VBA comment syntax".

The regex you have come up with works even better than what I had when I gave up the regex approach.

Well done!

The problem is that you can't parse VBA comments with a regex.

In [Lexers vs Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842809/1188513), [@SasQ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3614928/1188513) does a good job at explaining Chomsky's grammar levels:

> **Level 3: Regular grammars**
>
> They use **regular expressions**, that is, they can consist only of the
>   symbols of alphabet (a,b), their concatenations (ab,aba,bbb etd.), or
>   alternatives (e.g. a|b). They can be implemented as finite state
>   automata (FSA), like NFA (Nondeterministic Finite Automaton) or better
>   DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton). **Regular grammars can't handle
>   with nested syntax, e.g. properly nested/matched parentheses
>   (()()(()())), nested HTML/BBcode tags, nested blocks etc.** It's because
>   state automata to deal with it should have to have infinitely many
>   states to handle infinitely many nesting levels.
>
> **Level 2: Context-free grammars**
>
> They can have **nested, recursive, self-similar branches in their syntax
>   trees**, so they can handle with nested structures well. They can be
>   implemented as state automaton with stack. This stack is used to
>   represent the nesting level of the syntax. In practice, they're
>   usually implemented as a top-down, recursive-descent parser which uses
>   machine's procedure call stack to track the nesting level, and use
>   recursively called procedures/functions for every non-terminal symbol
>   in their syntax. But they can't handle with a context-sensitive
>   syntax. E.g. when you have an expression x+3 and in one context this x
>   could be a name of a variable, and in other context it could be a name
>   of a function etc.
>
> **Level 1: Context-sensitive grammars**

Regular Expressions simply aren't the appropriate tool for solving this problem, because whenever there's more than a single quote (/apostrophe), or when double quotes are involved, you need to figure out whether the left-most apostrophe in the code line is inside double quotes, and if it is, then you need to match the double quotes and find the left-most apostrophe after the closing double quote - actually, the left-most apostrophe that isn't part of a string literal, is your comment marker.

My understanding is that VBA comment syntax is a *context-sensitive grammar* (level 1), because the apostrophe is only your marker if it's not part of a string literal, and to figure out whether an apostrophe is part of a string literal, the easiest is probably to walk your string left to right and to toggle some `IsInsideQuote` flag as you encounter double-quotes... but only if they're not escaped (doubled-up). Actually you don't even check to see if there's an apostrophe inside the string litereal: you just keep walking until open quotes are closed, and only when the "in-quotes flag" is `False` you found a comment marker if you encounter a single quote.

Good luck!

---

Here's a test case you're missing:

```
s = "abc'def ""xyz""'nutz!" 'string with apostrophes and escaped double quotes
```

If you don't care about capturing the string literals, you can simply ignore the escaped double quotes and see 3 string literals here: `"abc'def "`, `"xyz"` and `"'nutz!"`.

---

This C# code outputs `'string with apostrophes and escaped double quotes` (all in-string double quotes are escaped with a backslash in the code), and works with all the test strings I gave it:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instruction = "s = \"abc'def \"\"xyz\"\"'nutz!\" 'string with apostrophes and escaped double quotes";
        // var instruction = "s = \"the cat's hat\"    ' quote within string -- works";
        // var instruction = "dim s as string ' string should be set to \"ten\"";

        int? commentStart = null;

        var isInsideQuotes = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < instruction.Length; i++)
        {
            if (instruction[i] == '"')
            {
                isInsideQuotes = !isInsideQuotes;
            }

            if (!isInsideQuotes && instruction[i] == '\'')
            {
                commentStart = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (commentStart.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instruction.Substring(commentStart.Value));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

---

Then if you want to capture *all legal comments*, you need to handle the legacy `Rem` keyword, and consider line continuations:

```
Rem this is a legal comment
' this _
    is also _
    a legal comment
```

In other words, `\r\n` in itself isn't enough to correctly identify all end-of-statement tokens.

A proper lexer+parser seems the only way to capture all comments.