# Finding VBA Comments using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, comments

I am trying to find all VBA comments using regular expressions. I have something that mostly works, but there are a few exceptions that I cannot figure out.

Expression I am using:

```
'(?!.*").*
```

Take our test code:

```
Working - This is a test 'This should be captured
Working - "this is a test" 'This should be captured
Not Working - "this is a test" 'This should be "captured"
Not Working - This is a test 'This should be "captured"
Working - "this is a test 'this should not capture'" 'this should capture
Working - "this isn't a test" 'this should capture
```

Here is a link to this example in RegExr: http://regexr.com/3f24h

For some reason that third and fourth examples are not capturing. The problem seems to be with having a string value in the comments and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Any advice?

Comment: The third one contains a double quote and a substring after `'` cannot have a double quote due to `(?!.*")` lookahead condition.

Comment: Try `'(?!\*\*)(?!\*  )[^']*$` with `regexp.Multiline=True`.

Comment: Give it a try here https://regex101.com/

Comment: This works but gets weird at the last line, it goes rogue and grabs everything. http://regexr.com/3f24h

Comment: Actually, it is because `[^']` matches line break characters. You can use `'(?!\*\*)(?!\* )[^'\n\r]*$`. BTW, if you test lines as separate strings, this won't be any problem. If it works for you, I will post.

Comment: it failed on this:     "don't capture this"

Comment: That's right. Actually, the context may be much more complex, and usually you need a parser to get these comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to capture VBA comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044801/regex-to-capture-vba-comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
^(?:[^"'\n]*("(?:[^"\n]|"")*"))*[^"]*'(.*)$
```

It handles multiple quoted strings, as well as strings having quoted (double) `"`'s (which I believe is VBA's way).

(I **guarantee** it will fail in some cases, but probably will work in most ;)

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ezrolT/2).

**Edit**

Added some of Comintern's examples and adjusted the regex. It still can't handle the *bracketed identifiers* though (which I don't even know what it means :S See the last line). But it now handles his continued line comments.

```
^(?:[^"'\n]*(?:"(?:[^"\n]|"")*"))*[^']*('(?:_\n|.)*)
```

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ezrolT/3).

Comment: One small tweak I'd suggest - the line continuation operator is only treated as a line continuation if it is preceded by a single space: `\s_\n`. I added an example at the bottom of my top code block (the one with broken syntax highlighting...).

Comment: "Just doing my masters bidding" ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can't find all of the comments (let alone string literals) in VBA code with regular expressions - period.  Trust me, I tried during work on the Smart Indenter module of [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) (in case that wasn't explicit enough - full disclosure, I'm a contributor). You'll need to actually parse the code.  The first issue that you'll run into are line continuations:

```
'Comment with a line _
continuation

Debug.Print 'End of line comment _
with line continuation.

Debug.Print 'Multiple line continuation operators _ _
still work.

Debug.Print 'This is actually *not* a line continuation_
Debug.Print 42
```

This makes it difficult to identify string literals, especially you're using line-by-line processing:

```
Debug.Print 42 'The next line... _
"...is not a string literal"
```

You also have to handle the old `Rem` comment syntax...

```
Rem old school comment
```

...which also support line continuations:

```
Rem old school comment with line _
continuation.
```

You might be thinking "that can't be so bad, Rem has to start a line".  If you are, you forgot about the statement separator (`:`)...

```
Debug.Print 42: Rem statement separator comment.
```

...or its evil twin the statement separator combined with a line continuation:

```
Debug.Print 42: Rem this can be _
continued too.
```

You covered a couple of the issues with sorting out string literals and comments like these...

```
Debug.Print "Unmatched double quotes." 'Comment"
Debug.Print "Interleaved single 'n double quotes." 'Comment"
```

...but what about bracketed identifiers like this beast (courtesy of @ThunderFrame)?

```
'No comments or strings in the line below.
Debug.Print [Evil:""Comment"'here]
```

Note that the *syntax highlighter SO uses* doesn't even catch all of these bizarre corner cases.

Comment: How does the VBE syntax highligher catches all of them?

Comment: @Vityata - The VBE syntax highlighter doesn't use regex - it parses the code.

Comment: Something I thought immediately after writing my comment. Btw, in your last example with the `Evil`, are you missing `"`?

Comment: @Vityata - Anything inside a bracketed identifier is treated as part of the identifier itself - the context of the characters themselves switches inside the brackets.

Comment: Identifier as a named range? Or something else?

Comment: @Vityata - In Excel, it's treated as an expression (so you can use it for named ranges).  It can also be used as a COM member call - i.e. `ws.[_CheckSpelling]`.  I doubt that you'd run into anything in COM with a member name containing quotes, but it may be feasible in that objects are free to implement `GetIDsOfNames` however they want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
("[^"]+"\s)?'.+
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/dd60QS/1